# About iOS code signing strategy - what happens when we archive a project without code signing, and export it with profile later?

Tags: ios, code-signing, provisioning-profile

I have some questions about code signing strategy, according to the sequence of signing (which I couldn't reached the answer by searching).

That is,

- What happens when we DON'T provide any code signing identity and profile on ARCHIVE, and then we DO provide them on EXPORTING step? for example,

```sh
xcodebuild archive \
    -project <ProjectName>.xcodeproj \
    -sdk iphoneos \
    -scheme <SchemeName>
    -configuration Release \
    CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY="" \#disable code sign 
    CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED=NO \#disable code sign
    CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED=NO \#disable code sign
```

Above is the code for archive without code sign.
And below, for exporting, I provide profile using `exportOptions.plist`.

```sh
xcodebuild -exportArchive -archivePath <ProjectName>.xcarchive -exportOptionsPlist <ProjectName>/exportOptions.plist -exportPath <ProjectName>.ipa
```

Is this available for app-store distribution, if I used profile with distribution option?

- Are these right options to provide details of provisioning profile, when archiving the project? (I've search a lot of examples but the answers are slightly different).

```sh
xcodebuild archive \
    -project <ProjectName>.xcodeproj \
    -sdk iphoneos \
    -scheme <SchemeName> \
    -configuration Release \
    CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY="****...D21C78" \
    PROVISIONING_PROFILE="********-****-..."
```

the code above keeps making the error : `<ProjectName> requires a provisioning profile. Select a provisioning profile in the Signing & Capabilities editor`, even though I'm working on CLI.

If there's any solution for questions, please guide me. Any document / paper or other materials that can be referred are fine too.

Answer (score 0):

(Self answering my question)

So, for the first question, I've done number of experiments and found out that  empty-signed archive can be exported, but cannot be deployed to the device.

To correctly deploy the ipa(exported) file, the archived one should be signed using codesign command.

And to do so, they should contain entitlements and codesign identity.

`codesign -s {IDENTITY} --entitlements {PATH_TO_ENTITLEMENTS_FILE} ... {PROJECT_PATH}/~~~/{NAME}.app`

For the second question, I couldn't find the answer, but using the strategy like empty-signing-archive -> codesign -> export can be the alternative.